# Postgres Group by ignore nulls

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I want to do should really be basic but for some reason I can't figure it out. Consider the following:

```
ID, COL1, COL2
1   'A'   NULL
1   NULL  'B'
```

I want to group on ID and 'squeeze out' the gaps and get:

```
ID, COL1, COL2
1   'A'   'B'
```

I'm probably having a black out as this sounds a very sqly problem/solution. This on a very large data set  with many rows and columns so efficiency would be important

Comment: What if there's a third row `1, 'C', 'C'`?

Comment: Sorry, this behavior is not clear to me. Please edit your answer and add this use case and your expected output.

Comment: Sorry my response above was incorrect and   I'm on a phone and can't format the question correctly. Essentially what I'm trying to do is reduce the size of this data set which has been comprised from a few sources. For the above example I only need 2 rows. 1 row comprising of A,B and one C,C. kind of distinct on col1, col2 but ignoring nulls

Comment: My problem is: Can there be more rows with same ID with values != NULL. For example: ID 1, but three rows with col1 values = A, NULL, C. If so, what value as to be chosen: A or C or {A,C} or MAX... I understood that you want two resulting rows with A and C. Is this correct? So you jsut want to eliminate the NULL values? But if you have to columns: Both of yours and a third row [1CC], two possible results can happen: [1AB, 1CC] or [1AC, 1CB]. It would be important to know what is your expected result and what is the algorithm how to chose the right one. It is far more complicated with more rows

Answer (score 3):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dad88d933a6c3dafd40815ab2263d8d0)

You could simply use an aggregate function which "removes" `NULL` values. `MAX` doesn't chose `NULL` if there's another value for example:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    MAX(col1) as col1, 
    MAX(col2) as col2
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```